# Sharepoint - send email if list item hasn't been updated in 48 hours

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

Fairly new SharePoint developer here,

Our customer is using SharePoint 2010. They have a list of WorkOrder items to track help desk requests.  Our customer wants to have the system send an email to the list item creator if the item has not been modified in 48 hours.

What would be the best way to go about setting this up?  Will I need a timer job? a workflow? I'm really not sure how to have the email trigger after a specified amount of time. Then if the item is modified, the 48 hour counter should start over again and send another email if it is not modified.

Thanks in advance for advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SharePoint Designer Workflow should help you, make the workflow to run on Item Creation as well as Item Updation!

Add Action "Pause for Duration", give 48 hours as time and check status if already modified then don't Email else Email to Created By!

The only thing I am worried is you want recurrence of workflow, even after update it should wait for 48 hours and if Item is not again updated it should fire an email, for this you should use Modified field, check if Modified - Current Time is less than 48 hours then don't email otherwise email..

I hope this helps